# Store create works, store define not

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I got a store for messages and it worked fine.

Now I need the same store, but with different initialization so I wanted to reuse it.

Before:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    model: 'my.MessageModel',
    storeId: 'importantStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',

        url: 'ajax/ajAsProof.php',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'messages',
            idProperty: 'id'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            allowSingle: false,
            encode: true,
            root: 'messages'
        }
    },
    ...
}

Ext.define('my.MessagesGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store: 'myGrid',
    ...
}
Ext.create('my.MessageGrid', {
    store:'importantStore',
    renderTo: 'myGridId'
});
```

After:

```
Ext.define('my.ImportantStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    model: 'my.MessageModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',

        url: 'ajax/ajAsProof.php',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'messages',
            idProperty: 'id'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            allowSingle: false,
            encode: true,
            root: 'messages'
        }
    },
    ...
}
Ext.define('my.MessagesGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store: 'myGrid',
    ...
}

var importantStore = Ext.create('my.ImportantStore', {
    storeId: 'importantStore',
    ... // my custom settings to come here, like filters or parameters
});
Ext.create('my.MessageGrid', {
    store:'importantStore',
    renderTo: 'myGridId'
});
```

This fails. Firefox/Firebug gives me a

> TypeError: url is undefined                 ext-all-debug.js (line 14429)
>
> this.$cache = dom.id ? Ext.cache[dom.id] : null;

All defined in the same js file within the Ext.ready() call. ExtJS 4.2.1.883 used.

Any ideas on what's wrong? Doing the same to make the grid reusable works fine, but fails with the store.

Comment: 1.-You shouldn't declare all in tbe same js. 2.- you should use something like "MyApp.store.ImportantStore" best regards

Comment: It's a small project, basically considering only out of 2 or 3 grids who use the same store, but different filtering options on it. The grid definition & creating works fine too in the same file, store doesn't. Any ideas what may causing it?

Comment: Even if it is only for a couple of grids I highly recommend you to adhere to Ext4 MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of looking for a reply I got the solution, mostly by coincidence... coming from C# background I wasn't aware of the prototypean horrors that comes with ExtJS and JavaScript.

```
Ext.define('my.ImportantStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    model: 'my.MessageModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    constructor: function(config) {
        config = config || {};

        this.initConfig(config);
        this.proxy = Ext.create('Ext.data.proxy.Ajax', {
            extraParams: config.extraParams
            // other config
        });
        ...
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.create('my.ImportantStore', {
    storeId: 'importantStore',
    extraParams: {
        ...
    }
});
```

If the components (in this case the proxy) isn't created within the container, when using `Ext.define` the proxy (or settings for that case) will be shared above all instances, which is counter intuitive for people who were familiar with OOP programming and class inheritance and never worked with prototype styled inheritance which works via cloning.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain yourself for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

> "url is undefined"

Are you actually putting some value to url config on your store ?

```
Ext.define('my.ImportantStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    model: 'my.MessageModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    url: '../myServletOrRestService'  // do you have this config ?

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yea, the configuration is exactly same in both cases. The only difference is that on define I additionally add the `extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',` to the configuration. Updated the post for more clarity

Comment: I see ... humm I would try defining some other class and then try to use it just to be sure that the way you are defining the calsses is not the issue but something specific to that store. Best regards.